# How can I get a complete listing of users or groups in ADFS?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, adfs, adfs2.1

How can I get a complete listing of users or groups in ADFS?

I know OpenAM has REST APIs to do that, is there something similar in ADFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - ADFS OOTB just provides a Federation layer on top of AD.

It does not open up any AD API's.

You'll have to do that with standard AD functionality.

Or add some custom code ...